# Spring @Value only uses default value

Tags: java, spring

I am injecting a value to a variable with `@Value`. For some reason, when I have the default value, it only uses it, it doesn't look for it in the properties file. When I'm not using the default value, it does inject the value from the properties file. No other configurations were changed.

```
@Value("${migration.paths:#{'classpath:db/migration'}}")
private String dbMigrationPaths;
```

(I'm using SPEL in the default value because it has slashes)

The property file configuration:

```
 @Bean
 public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configDataSourcesPropertyFile() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        bean.setLocations(new ClassPathResource[]{
                new ClassPathResource("/file1"),
                new ClassPathResource("/file2")
        });
        bean.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        bean.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
        return bean;
    }
```

Both are properties files, and the property in question resides in `file1` and not in `file2`

Comment: Please take a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369582/spring-boot-spring-always-assigns-default-value-to-property-despite-of-it-bein), seems a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have two property placeholders in your project? If yes, you may be running into this bug documented here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9989. See at the end there is a link to suggested workaround.