# Spring @Value annotation value overwritten by default value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We're implementing Spring Boot application (v2.2.5) and there is a configuration that use @Value annotation as below (`org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value`).

```
@Value("${something.about:abcd}")
private String somethingAbout;
```

In the `application.yml` file, we have property like this.

```
something:
  about: real_value
```

In this @Value annotation, I intended to work that as below:

1. Use the property value when it's defined in the application.yml file.
2. Otherwise, use the default value(abcd)

However, it does not read and set the existing property value to the variable. The variable is set as "abcd".

```
@Value("${something.about}") // Works fine

@Value("${something.about:abcd}") // It uses 'abcd' even the property exist
```

Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: "the defaultValue" is literally  "defaultValue" or (the identifier) of some other property?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say is it `null` or is it the value you set as a default? Is this a normal configuration class or are you using a properties class and mistakenly use `@Value`.

Comment: I wonder whether you have configured more than one property placeholder. If so you might hit https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/14623.

Comment: @xerx593 Sorry. I've updated the question to make it clear. the "defaultValue" was meant to the iterally "defaultValue" (changed to "abcd")

Comment: ok, "abcd" sounds more "constant" :), but then still "The variable is set as null." confuses (as the whole problem...it should work..even in spring-boot:2.2x)

Comment: @xerx593 I'm very sorry. I've missed to update the `null` part. I've updated it to "abcd" also. 
What exactly I want to ask is "the default value(abcd) overwrites the property value even if it exist".

Comment: Possibly answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369582/spring-boot-spring-always-assigns-default-value-to-property-despite-of-it-bein

Comment: yeah, this issue is was opened in 2012 (way outdated for this spring-versions), *but* [latest comment was last year](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/14623#issuecomment-887415779), and it had to do with `PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer`!! (you have such bean configured?)

Comment: @xerx593 M. Deinum  user17820797
Thank you for the help. As you recommended, I've found the cause of the issue. When I remove a annotation usage (A Swagger related annotation like spring fox) it work fine. 

Thanks

Comment: @HosangJeon consider adding the solution as an answer and accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Based on the helpful comments on the question, I'll summarize the cause and solution here.*

**Cause**

- The @Value property overwritten by default value issue is occurred
  because of the **multiple `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` behavior**.
- We had an old version of Springfox for using Swagger and there was a
  bean declaration for `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. It caused
  multiple behaviour with the original
  `PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer` in the spring-context.
- Eventually, the proper property value written in `application.yml`
  file was overwritten the default value because of the multiple
  behavior of `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean in Springfox old
  version.
- You can see the details from here :
  https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1621

**Solution**

- The known issue of Springfox has been resolved since version 2.7.0.
- I've resolved the issue **by updating the Springfox version to 3.0.0** to remove the duplicate `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` declaration.